# ReactNative+rxJs+typescript example

Tags: typescript, react-native, rxjs

Can some one share any sample app around typescript and rxjs with react native?I have to develop a react native app with ts and rxjs and I am not sure how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bassihassan/xreactive-react-native-storage

This is a very simple example that puts together all you need